# Using SQL query gives error message

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create a report with iReport by using below query which runs fine on SSRS reports. I'm new to JasperReports. How can I declare variables inside the report query? Here is my SQL query:

```
 Declare @SDate as Date
    Declare @EDate as Date
    Declare @JNumber as Char(8)


    set @SDate = case When @StartDate > '1/1/2000' Then @StartDate Else GETDATE() End
    set @EDate = case When @EndDate > '1/1/2000' Then @EndDate Else GETDATE() End
    set @JNumber = ISNULL(@JobNumber, '')

    select Distinct
    j.JobNumber, j.CustomerRep, j.JobStatus, j.StatusDate, a.Answer14 'Ship Time' ,j.LastShippedDate, Cast(m.ExpectedDate as Date) 'ShipDate',
    m.CustomerCode, RTrim(m.CustLongName) , RTrim(m.[Description]) 'JobName', RTrim(m.PONumber) 'PONumber', m.ProductCode, m.QuantityOrdered, a1.answer8'Pages'

     from JobExtra j (NOLOCK)
    Join JobMaster m (nolock) on m.JobNumber = j.JobNumber

where (@JNumber != '' AND @JNumber = j.JobNumber)
    And @SDate <= Cast(ISNULL(ce.sStartDate, m.StartDate) As Date)
  And @EDate >= Cast(ISNULL(ce.sStartDate, m.StartDate) As Date)


order by Case When @Sort = 'Ship Date' Then m.ExpectedDate When @Sort = 'Start Date' Then m.StartDate Else j.JobNumber End
, j.JobNumber, ce.sEndDate, ce.sEndTime, ce.sStartDate
```

The error is:

```
Error:java.sql.SQLException:Must Declare the scalar variable @StartDate
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: this is the error message-Error:java.sql.SQLException:Must Declare the scalar variable @StartDate

Comment: Then I suppose the variable `@StartDate` has no `Declare @StartDate as Date`. Same might be as well with `@EndDate`. You can add `Parameters` in those reports. They can be used with `P{your_parameter_name}` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have missed two variables.Please Declare variables @StartDate And @EndDate similarly like @SDate and @Edate

Ex:
Declare @StartDate Date
Declare EndDate Date

Please try it once

Thanks,
Dhana